# How to ensure that my model is using all available GPU in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, nvidia

I am using `tensorflow 2.3` dedicated with `2-GPU's`. I am using `styleformer` model to get informal to formal sentences. I want to use all `2-GPU's` for this task.

**Here is the information about GPU:**

```
!nvidia-smi

| NVIDIA-SMI XXX.XX.XX   Driver Version: ********    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  Off  | 00000000:89:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   34C    P0    42W / 300W |      0MiB / 32510MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100-SXM2...  Off  | 00000000:8A:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   35C    P0    43W / 300W |      0MiB / 32510MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+


from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

def get_available_gpus():
    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    return [x.name for x in local_device_protos if x.device_type == 'GPU']

['/device:GPU:0', '/device:GPU:1']
```

**Code that I am using on GPU**

```
from styleformer import Styleformer
import torch
import warnings

sf = Styleformer(style = 0) 

source_sentences = [
"I am quitting my job",
"Jimmy is on crack and can't trust him",
"What do guys do to show that they like a gal?"
]   

for source_sentence in source_sentences:
    target_sentence = sf.transfer(source_sentence, inference_on=1, quality_filter=0.95, max_candidates=5)
```

In the above code `inference_on=1` means we are using GPU. But how can I ensure it's using both GPU. I went to the `transfer` function inside `styleformer` package and found this line..

```
def transfer(self, input_sentence, inference_on=0, quality_filter=0.95, max_candidates=5):
      if self.model_loaded:
        if inference_on == 0:
          device = "cpu"
        elif inference_on == 1:
          device = "cuda:0"  
        else:  
          device = "cpu"
          print("Onnx + Quantisation is not supported in the pre-release...stay tuned.")
```

**How can I change the above code to use both GPU's?**

Answer (score 1):

your model is not using the GPU, there could be multiple reasons,

1. you did not install the Cuda toolkit & drivers for the GPU to access in the developer mode
2. Nvidia Driver issue ( uninstall & install)
3. Tensorflow version issue

check all these and try again. The notebook will take GPU automatically if it is available for use if you have everything installed.

When it is running on GPU, you will see 0MiB / 32510MiB will change to more then 0MiB.

Vote it if you found it correct !!! will help others to follow the same !!

Comment: The notebook is deployed using all GPU drivers you mentioned. It's customized kernel. The Output above is not running any process now. My Question does it pick both GPU automatically?

Comment: No, it will not, it will take any one of the GPUs only, GPU Cluster training and distribution works differently and little complex to set up. it will automatically pick the GPU number: 0.

Comment: @MAC use this link below which can help you to setup,
https://towardsdatascience.com/train-a-neural-network-on-multi-gpu-with-tensorflow-42fa5f51b8af

Comment: Can you show how it can be achieved in above scenario. Since I am not training any model but inferencing.

Comment: if you are inferencing,  once GPU is more than enough considering the input data wont exceed the GPU memory size

Comment: @MAC, also check the nvidia smi parallelly, if there is any fluctuation when you do the inference, then it is using the GPU.